# Get user's last input in aiml

Tags: input, tags, aiml

Instead of getting the bot's last response with 'that' i would like to know if there is any way I can get the user's previous input to see if the user typed the same statement again and  respond accordingly instead of simply parroting the same response over and over again. Is there any tag in AIML for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input index=n tag for this

Answer (score 0):

As you said, < input index="n"/ > should work. N=1 for the most recent input etc.